# Any reasons for the E-commerce angular app's product pages showing different source code when viewing it in the browser view source?

Tags: angular, caching, prerender

Recently, I have noticed this type of issue in an angular app. Any reasons for this issue? Any tools to track it?

Issue: E-commerce angular app earlier created product pages showing different source code when viewing it in the browser view source.

Actual Result: Different type of view source is showing for earlier created products. But newly created products showing the correct source code. When changing the earlier created product's URL, it is then showing the correct source code.

Expected Result: All the product pages should show the correct source code.

Note: No Server side cached (Varnished or Memcached), CDN or GTM custom HTML tags have implemented. Hosted with the Amazon hosting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the root cause of this issue. I just want to share it with you, just in case if you would face a similar situation and look for the solutions.

I have found earlier pre-rendered static HTML pages in the server root folder with the same URL path.

```
Ex: /products/productname/index.html
```

Hence, when we are viewing the browser view source, it is showing that old static HTML page content instead of the correct source code. This issue got resolved after removing those old static HTML pages. I hope this might be helpful to someone else too.

Thanks.